# dont have running shoes gem (Fedora)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shoes

I installed heme shoes
`sudo gem install shoes`, but when you run a primitive application such as:

```
require 'Shoes'
Shoes.app { button("Click me!") { alert("Good job.") } }`
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- Shoe (LoadError)
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
from shoes.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: try `require 'shoes'` (lowercase). Also your error seems to state you wrote `require 'Shoe'` (no "s"). Also I would not recommend calling your file `shoes.rb` as this is the same name as the gem and could potentially cause collisions.

Comment: Error: 
Sorry, this gem currently does nothing. Team Shoes is working on Gemifying Shoes, and this is just a placeholder until then.
guish.rb:3:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Shoes (NameError)

Comment: Okay I am not sure what your question is then? Since Shoes is not a gem you will have to supply the full path e.g. `require '/path/to/where/you/installed/shoes/lib/shoes'` and then it will work fine if that is your issue (like I said it is a bit unclear from your question). You could also try using the pre release of shoes 4 by using `gem install shoes --pre` but not everything is working just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current shoes gem does not work and it never did (it is a place holder). What does work are the preview versions of the shoes 4 gem, for which you need JRuby though. Then you can do `gem instal shoes --pre`.

Shoes3 has to be downloaded as it's its whole own thing (with an own ruby interpreter etc.)